# What are these sections of the screen called, and how do I move between them?

Tags: vimrc

I'm new to vim and stuck in one of these windows; I couldn't move to the others.
[image: window screen shot]
They are not tabs; I tried `:tabnew` to make sure.

How can I move between them? What are they called?

Comment: do you mean *windows* and please see `:h window-move-cursor`

Comment: if you add `set mouse=a` to your config, you can place your cursor on one of the windows using your mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called 'windows' see `:help windows`

To move between them, use `ctrl + w` + `j/k/h/l` (see `:help window-move-cursor`, which is section 4 of the general help above)

##### Useful info from [a different answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69780306/14467607)

It is very useful to grasp the concept of
buffers vs tabs vs windows in vim, since most other editing environments use
tab pages in the same way that vim uses buffers...

See `:help 22.4` and `:help windows` and `:help tabpage` to sort out how they
relate to each other. Also see this [blog
post](https://joshldavis.com/2014/04/05/vim-tab-madness-buffers-vs-tabs/) that
lays out the differences well.

Comment: Some more links: [buffers, windows, tabs](https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/buffers-windows-tabs/)
[vim buffers over tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26708822/why-do-vim-experts-prefer-buffers-over-tabs)
[vim tab madness](https://joshldavis.com/2014/04/05/vim-tab-madness-buffers-vs-tabs/)